# c# UWP How to schedule something to run after current Dispatcher.ProcessEvents()? Is it even possible?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

Im trying my hand at creating a very simple "game engine" to play around in universal platform and Win2D.

I want to create a "main game loop" that can be started and stopped.

```
public async void StartGameLoop()
{           
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
        GameLoopStopSignal = false;
        while (!GameLoopStopSignal)
        {
            //something like good old DoEvents()?
            CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessAllIfPresent);

            //Game Tick
            Tick();
        }
    });
}
public void StopGameLoop()
{
    GameLoopStopSignal = true;
}
```

If I call StartGameLoop() right in some page's "Loaded" event, everything works like a charm.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartGameLoop();//all good
}
```

But if I do call StartGameLoop() inside a button's "click" event I get a catastrophic failure exception stating "Nested calls to ProcessEvents method is not allowed.", witch can actually make some sense.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartGameLoop();//will cause exception on Dispatcher.ProcessEvents()
}
```

So I'm searching for a way to be sure the game loop starts after any potentially running ProcessEvents() call when I click on those UI buttons.. and I'm fresh out of ideas :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `await Task.Yield();`

This tells the dispatcher to process anything after the yield when it's done processing. This is not guaranteed... the dispatcher decides what's priority, but give it a try and see if it's what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield(v=vs.110).aspx

Just an example, try this:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
{
    GameLoopStopSignal = false;
    while (!GameLoopStopSignal)
    {
        //something like good old DoEvents()?
        CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessAllIfPresent);

        await Task.Yield();
        //Game Tick
        Tick();
    }
});
```

Note the `async () => {...}` in the `RunAsync` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot ill try this after work and let you know

Comment: It was a very good idea but unfortunately does not change anything I can see

Comment: However playing around I'm beginning to think I dont need the Dispatcher.ProcessEvent() call anyway.. thanks for the tip tho, I didn't know about task yielding

Comment: OK so for the record the Task.Yield() call is basically doing what I wanted to do with the Dispatcher.ProcessEvent(), that is giving an oportunity to the system to process inputs / events before going into another Tick(). <

Comment: Please don't say that `DoEvents` was ever "good old" - it was not. `DoEvents` was a horrible thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I reverted to using Task.Run() (hence running the main loop on the thread pool) instead of running on the CoreWindow.Dispatcher (in the main UI thread); seems to bypass all the problems I had. Not sure if its gonna come back to bite me in the end but finger crossed.

```
public void StartGameLoop()
{           
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        GameLoopStopSignal = false;
        clock.Start();
        while (!GameLoopStopSignal)
        {
            Tick();
        }
        clock.Stop();
    });
}
```